# How to print data from database in a pdf file using jsp?

Tags: mysql, jsp, pdf

I am a bit new to jsp and was working on a project in NetBeansIDE 8.0, where i need to retrieve data from mysql workbench and print that data into a pdf file say "HelloWorld.pdf" in the D drive.I was using itext7-7.0.2 and itextpdf-5.3.5.jar for it.I was using jsp for doing this.Here is my code :

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Element"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Document"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Chunk"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Font"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.OutputStream"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Anchor"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter"%>
<%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.PageSize" %>
<%@page import="java.io.IOException" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@page import="javax.naming.Context" %>
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.ServletException" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse" %>
<%@page import="javax.sql.DataSource" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<% 
    Document doc = new Document();
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/HelloWorld.pdf")));
doc.open();
String branch1 =request.getParameter("branch");
String sem1 =request.getParameter("semester");
String sub =request.getParameter("subject");

  Font bfBold18 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(0, 0, 0)); 
  Font bfBold12 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLDITALIC, new BaseColor(0, 0, 0)); 
  Font bf12 = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);   
  try
{
    String t=null;
   PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, os); 
   doc.open();
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectdb","root","root");
   Statement st=con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("select qid,question from questiondb where branch='"+branch1+"' and semester='"+sem1+"' and subject='"+sub+"'");
    while(rs.next())
    { 
        t=rs.getString(2);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(t, bfBold18);
        paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        paragraph.setFont(new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.NORMAL));
       doc.add(paragraph);
        doc.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
    }      
       rs.first();  
       doc.close();
       con.close();
       os.flush();
       os.close();      
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    out.println(e);
}

%>
    </body>
</html>
```

But while running in GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 i am getting the error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`

Comment: in catch block use   e.printStackTrace(); instead of  out.println(e);

Comment: Done. But still no change in diagnosed Exception

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the response's  outputstream or call out.println(e). The exception you are getting is linked to how servlets work. Once the responses have been generated (by the servlet framework) you cannot use their output streams again

That said you should probably write your code inside a Java class instead of a JSP. The latter are usually for generating HTML pages only, not so much for invoking heavy logic like pdf generation